# A simple paper scissors rock game - how to add images for each selection?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, picturebox

My code so far:

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create a random variable
    Random r = new Random();
    int rr = r.Next(3);
    //Computer choice
    int CompChoice = rr;
    //User Choice
    int UserChoice = comboSelect.SelectedIndex;

    //Picks Pc Choice to play
    string pcChoice = "Rock";
    if (CompChoice == 1);         
    {
       pcChoice = "Paper";
    }
    if (CompChoice == 2);
    {
        pcChoice = "Scissors";
    }
    picBox2.Text = pcChoice;

    //Draw
    if (CompChoice == UserChoice)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Draw!");
```

Basically want to add images for each selection, say user picks rock - I have then "Rock_hand.jpg" and say comp picks paper, then "Paper_Hand.jpg" shows up in the picture boxes.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What type of application are you building? (web, desktop, ...?)

Comment: @AsheraH, is a desktop application.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the image displayed in you `PictureBox` by setting `Image` property:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("paper.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try if images names are `Rock.jpg`,`Paper.jpg` and `Scissors.jpg`

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(pcChoice+".jpg");
```